# start and end indices of consecutive strings - matlab

Tags: string, matlab

```
a = {'AHA','HQJ','KAL','BS','BS','BS','AKL','UQI','BS','BS','ALO','ZHT','KAH','KIO','AAL'}
```

I'm trying to find the start and end indices of consecutive `'BS'` strings.

In my example, that would be `[4, 6]` and `[9,10]`.

Answer (score 2):

There you go. Since you didn't show your attempt, I'll leave it to you to figure out how it works :-)

```
a = {'AHA','HQJ','KAL','BS','BS','BS','AKL','UQI','BS','BS','ALO','ZHT','KAH','KIO','AAL'};
b = 'BS';

t = [false strcmp(a(:).', b) false];
u = diff(t);
starts = find(u>0);
ends = find(u<0)-1;
result = num2cell([starts; ends].', 2);
```

In your example, this gives

```
>> celldisp(result)
result{1} =
     4     6
result{2} =
     9    10
```